# Using DESC as column name in DBF

Tags: c#, odbc, dbf, reserved-words

There is a column name as DESC in a dbf. When I try to use INSERT using C# ODBC it is giving an error as DESC cannot be a valid column name (I think). But I need to use only DESC for that column. How to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DESC is a reserved word, you need to enclose the column name in square brackets.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ([DESC]) VALUES ('My Description')
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found it myself :)